# close calendar after selected date in swift

Tags: swift

I used this Calendar
[image]

I want a date when I chose to be closed. 
I've added it to View

```
let date = NSDate()
        calendarView.selectedDates = [date]
        calendarView.selectionRangeLength = 1
        calendarView.maxMonths = 1
        calendarView.delegate = self
        calendarView.createCalendar()
        calendarView.center = self.view.center
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Are you presenting calendarView as a modal view controller?
If so you could use self.dismissViewControllerAnimated().

If the calendar is presented via a navigation controller you could use navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated() or use an unwind segue once a date is selected or a button is pressed: [What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)